# Creating an array for values of a square wave function

Tags: python, arrays, fft

I have a function shown below

```
f(t) = 1 : if 2t rounded down to the next lowest integer is even 

f(t) = -1 : if 2t rounded down to the next lowest integer is odd
```

I am trying to eventually carry out fourier transformations on the function but first I need to write a program to create an array of N=1000 elements containing 1000 equally spaced samples from a **single cycle** of this function which is a **square wave**.

How do I create this array ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the function part, can you be more precise?

Comment: f(t) = 
1 if ⌊2t⌋ is even,
−1 if ⌊2t⌋ is odd,

Comment: are you saying you want 1000 -1 and 1's alternating?

Comment: That isn't even correct syntax... confuse?

Comment: The OP asks for samples from a cycle of the [square wave function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareWave.html)

Comment: The important thing is to create the proper time samples from within a cycle before feeding them into the square wave function, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121147/creating-an-array-for-values-of-a-square-wave-function/34121965#34121965)

Answer (score 2):

As you ask for the values of the **square function within a cycle**, first you have to create the values for the **time samples**. Starting at `t=0` the function you mentioned has a cycle of 1, after `t=1` the function repeates itself.

For creating a sequence of equally spaced values between 0 and 1 there are several alternatives, but a straitght one is [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html?highlight=linspace#numpy.linspace). The first parameter is the starting time of the cycle, the second the end of the cycle and the third the number of samples (equally spaced). By using this you create the `t_samples`.

After that you just need to feed the square wave function (`square_func` in the code below) with the values stored in `t_samples`.

See an example here of how you can use it:

```
import numpy

def square_func(t):
    if int(2*t)%2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

t_samples = numpy.linspace(0.0,1.0,1000)

samples = [square_func(i) for i in t_samples]
```

The variable `samples` stores a list with the values you need (half of them are  '1s' and the other half '-1s', as we are referring to one cycle). The cycle of the function produced with this code is shown in the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function can be defined this way.

```
def f(t):
    return 1 if int(2 * t) % 2 == 0 else -1
```

And if you are using ***python 2.x*** you can use map to create the list.

```
N = 1000
sample = map(f, xrange(N)) # Or alternatively map(lambda n: f(n), xrange(N))
```

Comment: why not `map(f , xrange(N))`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I wanted to be verbose but I will add a comment :)

Comment: hmmm this code only returns the "1s" and no "-1s" why is that ?

Comment: @darren Are you testing with anything other than integers? Two times an integer is *always* going to be even, by definition. You need something like t=1.5 to produce -1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a method returning the sample value:

```
import math    

def f(t):
"""
f(t) = 1 if ⌊2t⌋ is even, −1 if ⌊2t⌋ is odd
"""
    if math.floor(2 * t) % 2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

The easiest way to generate your array would be to do:

```
a = [f(n) for n in xrange(1000)]
```

*Note: This assumes Python 2.x, use range if Python 3.x*

Comment: What if I set up an arange then set F=zeros(1000) then F[0:500]=1 and F[500:1000]=-1 ?

Comment: Here's the full prototype of the method: xrange(start, stop[, step])

Answer (score 0):

I ended up answering it in this way

```
F=zeros(1000)
F[0:500]=1
F[500:1000]=-1
```

Comment: Um, that's only *one* cycle, with very long period.

Comment: If you do this, you have to import **numpy**. If you want to avoid that a simpler solution is to replace your first line with `F = [0]*1000`.